# Create array of values in an if statement in Python

Tags: python

I want to create an array of values based on a condition.

```
data_total = [
    {"modele": "DS",
     "cote_actual": 10000},
    {"modele": "DS",
     "cote_actual": 12000},
    {"modele": "204",
     "cote_actual": 10000}]

for total in data_total:
    model = total["modele"]
    cote_actual = total["cote_actual"]
    model_ds = []

    if model == "DS":
        model_cote = cote_actual
        print(model_cote)
        model_ds.append(model_cote)
        print(model_ds)
```

The output I want:

```
"modele_ds" = [10000, 12000]
```

I mess with the loop, I don't have the input I need. I know I have to append or populate the array.

Comment: You are assigning a new empty list to `model_ds` on every iteration of the loop, I don't think that is what you want

Comment: Following @UnholySheep, you should define `model_ds` outside of the loop, if that wasn't already clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, you must assign model_ds list outside the loop, because having it inside the loop it gets empty with every iteration. Your code should be (line that changed is with comment):

```
data_total = [
    {"modele": "DS",
     "cote_actual": 10000},
    {"modele": "DS",
     "cote_actual": 12000},
    {"modele": "204",
     "cote_actual": 10000}]

model_ds = [] #assign model_ds outside the loop
for total in data_total:
    model = total["modele"]
    cote_actual = total["cote_actual"]
    if model == "DS":
        model_cote = cote_actual
        model_ds.append(model_cote)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(model_ds)

[10000, 12000]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ x['cote_actual'] for x in data_total if x['modele'] == 'DS‘]
```

Answer (score 0):

below

```
data_total = [
    {"modele": "DS",
     "cote_actual": 10000},
    {"modele": "DS",
     "cote_actual": 12000},
    {"modele": "204",
     "cote_actual": 10000}]

lst = [e['cote_actual'] for e in data_total if e['modele'] == 'DS']
print(lst)
```

output

```
[10000, 12000]
```